# Rxjava Observables dependency

Tags: android, rx-java

There something i want to accomplish with Observables but i cant think of a way of doing it.

Imagining i have:

- ObservableA
- ObservableB

In order to use ObservableB, i need the result from ObservableA.
After getting the result of ObservableB, i need to construct an Object
with the result of ObservableA and Observable B.

Which is the proper operator to do it=? I can't find any.

I tried with zip:

```
return Observable.zip(
        observableA.flatMap(A -> ObservableB(A))
        ,
        ObservableA
        , new Func2<B, A, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(B b, A a) {
                String ab = someFunction(a.someFunction());
                return new Object(a, ab, b);
            }
        });
```

But zip return items not another observable.

EDIT: I managed to get it done:

```
return Observable.zip(
            getRosterEntry(userXmppAddress).flatMap(rosterEntry -> getRosterPresence(rosterEntry.getUser()))
            ,
            getRosterEntry(userXmppAddress)
            , new Func2<Presence, RosterEntry, Friend>() {
                @Override
                public Friend call(Presence presence, RosterEntry rosterEntry) {
                    String finalUserXmppAddress = AppXmppUtils.parseXmppAddress(rosterEntry.getUser());
                    return new Friend(rosterEntry.getName(), finalUserXmppAddress, presence);
                }
            }).flatMap(Observable::just);
```

But it seems a little overcoded. Is there any other way of accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
getRosterEntry(userXmppAddress)
        .flatMap(new Func1<RosterEntry, Observable<Friend>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Friend> call(final RosterEntry rosterEntry) {
                return getRosterPresence(rosterEntry.getUser())
                        .map(new Func1<Presence, Friend>() {
                            @Override
                            public Friend call(Presence presence) {
                                String finalUserXmppAddress = AppXmppUtils.parseXmppAddress(rosterEntry.getUser());
                                return new Friend(rosterEntry.getName(), finalUserXmppAddress, presence);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```